# image cannot be seen on p:commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i want to display an image on p:commandButton , i have tried many ways but unable to show the image on the button.Below is the code i have included:
css code:

```
.ui-icon-myCancel{
    background-image: url("#{resources['images/cancel.jpg']}") !important;
}


 <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-myCancel" action="#{cancelMB.cancelList}" update="dataInfo" ajax="true"/>
```

I have image under **WebContent\resources\images\cancel.jpg**

The other way i tried modifying the css code as below but still no luck:

```
.ui-icon-myCancel{
       background-image: url(resources/images/cancel.jpg) no-repeat top left !important;
}
```

other way:

```
.ui-icon-myCancel{
       background-image: url(resources/images/cancel.jpg)
}
```

Please suggest , where iam going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution is to *abandon* CSS use here, and rely on a extra nested tag "graphicImage" inside not a `commandButton`, but a `commandLink` instead :

```
<p:commandLink action="#{cancelMB.cancelList}" update="dataInfo" ajax="true" >
     <h:graphicImage name="images/cancel.jpg" title="Cancel" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Thanks Omar, got it.but the issue is i want to have image on the button so that when i click that button it does some functinality. Now when i use as you mentioned above i can see one image and a command button.But i need to have image on the commandbutton.

Comment: Thanks Omar, it worked, i cannot accept your answer as reputation points are not enough for me to accept.